# Highchart drilldown toggle on bar as well

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I want drilldown to collapse to work when clicked on bar graph as well. Any help is appropriated.
Here is the sample code

```
series: [{
        name: 'Bucket',
        colorByPoint: true,
        data: [{
            name: 'Shopping',
            y: JSON.parse(data_arr['data_sh_1']), 
            drilldown: 'Shopping'
        }
```

Here is the example [demo example](http://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/FW64T/)

Comment: What do you mean? What are you trying to do, what's your code, and what is the problem that you're having?

Comment: The example says when i click on the bar the bar graph expands and  i get a button to make the bar graph collapse. But i want the same functionality that is for buuton on expanded the bar graph as well.

Comment: Im a little bit confused. You have drilldown, click on a column and new drilled points are visible. Button is printed. Click on the button and get back to initial level. Button disappears. Where you need to have a button?

Comment: I want to click on the drilldown bar and it should collapse as it collapse when click on the button. Basically i want the button functionality on the expanded bar chart as well.

Comment: Which bar? the bar you clicked to get the drilldown isn't there once you've drilled down...  just, any bar?

Comment: Yes i want to on the bar that comes after to drilldown to have the functionality of button.